# Clojure, replacing vars in let bindings causes performance issue?

Tags: replace, clojure, binding, var, let

Let's say there is a function and it received a json string which contains about 100KB of data. The string gets converted to a map and then it keeps associating new keys to that map and replacing the var in let bindings like below:

```
(defn myfn
  [str]
  (let [j (json/read-str str)
        j (assoc-in j [:key1 :subkey1] somedata1)
        j (assoc-in j [:key2 :subkey2] somedata2)
        ....
        j (assoc-in j [:key100 :subkey100] somedata100)]
    ... do something ...))
```

I know, after all those let bindings, j will have all those new keys added. This is just an example. I wonder what happens inside those lots of bindings to the same var.

I mean what happens in the memory. Would that copy 100KB 100 times in the memory? And it eats up 100KB * 100 = 10,000KB until it gets out of that function? Or, Clojure is smart enough and it actually keeps adding new keys in the same memory space?

If you could also recommend where I should look for in Clojure reference to find an answer to this, that would be really nice.

Comment: I actually often do this with strings to keep my code clean. I keep replacing vars in the bindings doing few things until I get the final value and then use that var in the exprs body. I didn't really care with strings, but this question came up when I was dealing with a pretty large map data in the bindings. I have no idea what actually happens in the memory.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure

Comment: Normally you would use `->>` in this situation. Maybe Clojure will cope better with the thread last macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clojure uses a data structure called a [`trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), that is similar to a tree, but which only has data at the leaf nodes.  Most of clojure's persistent structures are implemented as a trie.

[This excellent article](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1) really explains things in detail and uses vectors, so I won't rehash it here. I know on S.O. it's preferred to give the content rather than a link, but it's not a topic that can be covered fully in an answer here, and the article does it best, so I'll just link to it.

In short, when a data structure is modified in some way, a new trie is created for the new "version", and instead of copying all the data over from the old to the new with one change made, the nodes in the new structure point to existing data.  Here is a visualization from the above article that shows data sharing:

[image: Taken from http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1]

So, using this structure, we have shared data, but since it is only a binary trie, it can get deep very quickly, so lookups could take a very long time (for a vector of 1 billion elements, the depth to get to a leaf node is log<sub>2</sub>1e9 which is 30). To get around this, clojure uses a 32-way branching factor instead of a 2-way one, yielding trees that are *very* shallow. So, the same vector that holds 1 billion elements in clojure only takes log<sub>32</sub>1e9, or 6 levels of indirection, to reach the leaves.

I encourage you to read the article, and also have a look at [`PersistentHashMap`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f572a60262852af68cdb561784a517143a5847cf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentHashMap.java), and you will see references to `shift + 5` in several places.  This is a clever way to use bit-shifting to index into the trie (log<sub>2</sub>32 = 5).  See the [second part of the article](http://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-2) for more in-depth info on this.

To summarize, clojure uses efficient data structures to achieve persistence, and any language which features immutability as a core feature must do this, if it hopes to achieve usable performance.

Comment: The series of articles are great, trying to get the author to do one for associative data structures as well. Plus: There is a CHAMP implementation out there that apparently performs as well or better.

Comment: So for the answer of my own question, there is no 100 times, or not even 1 time of copying and Clojure efficiently takes care of data structure changing. Because I kept replacing one var in bindings, I won't have access to the older versions, but there is absolutely no copying the whole data map. After all those bindings, I would just have access to the final version that has all values linked to it. Thanks, Josh.